# Are there image NFTs you can "see" only if you bought it?

Tags: nft

I'm looking for examples or approaches to building a solidity contract similar to the standard NFT but with the difference that you can see only a preview of the actual image, made available by the NFT original owner, and you can access the complete image only by acquiring the NFT.

Are there any precedents of this type of NFT?

The applications of this type of NFT could range from lottery type NFT in which you don't know what you'll get until you pay for it, or maybe also some type of one-shot only fan were the NFT creator makes the NFT with a blurred preview and if you buy it you can access the full image.